# when to send response in async await try catch block

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have seen 2 different examples and would like to know which is 'right' or if it doesn't make much difference. Example 1 is sending the response inside the try and example 2 is sending outside of the try block.

Example 1:

```
  try {
    await food.save();
    res.status(201).send(food);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
```

Example 2:

```
  try {
    await food.save();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }

  res.status(201).send(food);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In first example, if `await food.save();` throws an error, then code below it won't execute and the execution will move to the `catch` block. Client will receive a response with status code of `500`.

In second example, if `await food.save();` fails, `catch` block will execute, server will send a response to the client with the status code of `500` and then the last statement will also execute which is probably not what you want. You will also get an error that you cannot re-send the headers once they have been sent. This is because your code will try to send the response to the client twice.

You should use first example because you only want to send the success response if the document is saved in the database successfully.